# Dock Icon twice of same instance and Non-Gui process wrongly tagged "not responding"

Tags: c++, macos, select, dock

I have a problem with my app written in C++.

After I started my app, it run 3 subprocesses. In the activity monitor it looks so:
MyApp
 - process1
 - process2
 - process3

process1 is a vncserver. If a client connects, the "process1" is now called "MyApp" and a second icon appears in the Dock.
I searched out that the icon appears after the function "select(..)" is called.
Why happened this?

If I call this at startup of process1 (in a external .mm file)

```
[NSApplication sharedApplication];
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited];
```

the second icon appears for very short time but disappears immediately. This solves my problem. But now my "process1" (now called "MyApp") is tagged as "not responding" in the activity monitor. The process runs and responds to the client. OSX now thinks my subprocess is a GUI process and tagged it with "not responding".
How can I prevent this?

EDIT:

The process "MyApp" starts 3 processes, a vncserver, a ftp client and a ssh client. The ftp and ssh client work fine. But the vncserver changes his process name and shows a second Dock icon. If I disable the icon, the process is tagged as "not responding" but still answers to connected clients.

The user may be confused about the second dock icon or the not responding process and thinks something went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The `vncserver` was located in the `Contents/MacOS` directory, but it have to be in `Contents/Resources`

That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the LSUIElement flag in the Info.plist for the relevant process, it will stop the icon appearing in the doc.

So add this to the info.plist file: -

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

This is documented under [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html).

Comment: The problem is that my app should stay in the Dock, but only once.

Comment: Sorry, then, I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by 3 subprocesses? I assumed it was 3 applications where one launches the other two and you wanted the other two to stop displaying in the dock.

Comment: the process "MyApp" starts 3 processes, a vncserver, a ftp client and a ssh client. The ftp and ssh client work fine. But the vncserver changes his process name and shows a second Dock icon. If I disable the icon, the process is tagged as "not responding" but still answers to connected clients.The user may be confused about the second dock icon or the not responding process and thinks something went wrong.

Comment: That's much clearer. I would suggest you change your question to include the comment you've made here.

Comment: Done. I hope now its better to understand

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you have one application which is just responsible for launching the other 3 applications? If so, I suggest you change the design. I would expect the vncserver to be a daemon process, with no UI, which is running independently and would have the LSUIElement set in its plist. The FTP and SSH clients should either be separate applications or just one with the functionality of both FTP and SSH.

Comment: No, my application is the main process (GUI, network) and the vncserver, FTP and SSH clients are only helpers. Changing the design is no option, because thats too much additional work for my company I'm workung for.

Comment: And are those helpers separate app bundles?

Comment: No, the helpers are single executables like command line tools.